# Get last 7 days date data

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to get Last 7 days Data count for each date(from today to 7th day past) from table in SQL Server, I'm using below query for getting result,

```
select convert(varchar(10),dDate,101),count(convert(varchar(10),dDate,101)) from tblPanDetails
where dDate BETWEEN GETDATE()-7 AND GETDATE()
group by convert(varchar(10),dDate,101)
```

Its working fine and result is(In database these date information only available from last 7 days)

```
Column1 Column2
02/19/2020  4
02/20/2020  1
02/21/2020  2
02/22/2020  3
02/25/2020  1
```

but i need if no data in date it will be 0, just like below,

```
column1     column2
02/25/2020      5
02/24/2020      0
02/23/2020      6
02/22/2020      2
02/21/2020      1
02/20/2020      0
02/19/2020      2
```

Kindly help me to get above result in SQL.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a temp table to dynamically generate the dates you would like. Then join this table with your table to form the count.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblCurrentDates') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tblCurrentDates
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tblPanDetails') IS NOT NULL  DROP TABLE #tblPanDetails

DECLARE @DateFrom DATE, @DateTo DATE
SET @DateFrom = GETDATE()-7
SET @DateTo = GETDATE()

-- Generate 7 days dates in temp table
SELECT DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@DateFrom) [Date]
INTO #tblCurrentDates
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P'
AND DATEADD(DAY,number+1,@DateFrom) < @DateTo 


-- This is your temp table, for testing purposes
SELECT dDate= CAST(GETDATE()-1 as DATE)
INTO #tblPanDetails


--SELECT All dates with their counts in your table including no values
SELECT 
Column1 = c.[Date],
Column2 =  COUNT(dDate) 
FROM #tblCurrentDates c
LEFT OUTER JOIN #tblPanDetails d on d.dDate = c.[Date]
GROUP BY dDate, [Date]
```

Comment: Great, but its return following result,
```
Column1 Column2
2/19/2020 12:00:00 AM 0
2/20/2020 12:00:00 AM 0
2/21/2020 12:00:00 AM 0
2/22/2020 12:00:00 AM 0
2/23/2020 12:00:00 AM 0
2/24/2020 12:00:00 AM 1
```
Actually my table consist  below data count on some dates,
02/19/2020 4
02/20/2020 1
02/21/2020 2
02/22/2020 3
02/25/2020 1

Comment: @Sathishkumar I gave you a standard solution, format the date like you would like. And use your own tables !

Answer (score 0):

You can easily construct 7 days of data in the query:

```
select v.dte, count(pd.dDate)
from (values (convert(date, getdate() - 7)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 6)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 5)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 4)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 3)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 2)),
             (convert(date, getdate() - 1))
      ) v(dte) left join             
      tblPanDetails pd
      on convert(date, pd.dDate) = v.dte
group by v.dte
order by v.dte;
```

Note that I left the first column as a date.  You can of course convert it to a string, but I prefer authentic dates.